# plpgsql operate on query before returning it

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'd like to write a plpgsql procedure that executes a select query, updates the row (if existing) and then returns the result.

For that I'd like to be able to handle the procedure call like a normal query with `SELECT nickname FROM use_session_token(...)`.

Usually I would use `RETURN QUERY(...)` but I want to update the row first (it's either one or none because `token` is a primary index)

But in fact I want the row only returned and updated if other criteria are fulfilled, so I can't just operate on the primary key itself.

I had two attempts, one using a `Refcursor` and the other one using `SELECT INTO`, but I fail to actually return a `SETOF users`.

My attempt with `SELECT INTO`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION use_session_token(Char(128), Inet) RETURNS SETOF users AS $$
DECLARE
  row Record;
BEGIN
  SELECT u.* INTO row FROM sessions AS t
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON (t.user_id = u.id)
  WHERE
    t.token=$1 AND
    t.date_last_used > NOW() - interval '30 minutes' AND
    t.ip_address=$2 AND
    u.is_deleted=FALSE AND
    EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM mail AS m
      WHERE m.user_id=u.id AND m.is_confirmed=TRUE AND m.is_deleted=FALSE
    )
  ;

  IF (row) THEN
    UPDATE sessions SET date_last_used=NOW() WHERE token=$1;
  ELSE
    -- maybe do other things if there is no result
  END IF;

  RETURN row;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

My attempt with `cursor`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION use_session_token(Char(128), Inet) RETURNS SETOF users AS $$
DECLARE
  cursor Refcursor;
  row Record;
BEGIN
  OPEN cursor SCROLL FOR (
    SELECT u.* INTO row FROM sessions AS t
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON (t.user_id = u.id)
    WHERE
      t.token=$1 AND
      t.date_last_used > NOW() - interval '30 minutes' AND
      t.ip_address=$2 AND
      u.is_deleted=FALSE AND
      EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM mail AS m
        WHERE m.user_id=u.id AND m.is_confirmed=TRUE AND m.is_deleted=FALSE
    )
  );

  FETCH cursor INTO row;

  IF (FOUND) THEN
    MOVE PRIOR cursor;
    UPDATE sessions SET date_last_used=NOW() WHERE CURRENT OF cursor;
  ELSE
    -- maybe do other things if there is no result
  END IF;

  RETURN row;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

But both attempts actually fail with the fact that I'm not really able to return a proper result set.

What would be the best way to accomplish that and to solve my problem?

And then, which of the both attempts is the better one (or is a third solution better)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt was the best (cursors tend to be slow), but you should use `RETURN NEXT` to return any rows from the function. With some other improvements, you get this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION use_session_token(Char(128), Inet) RETURNS SETOF users AS $$
DECLARE
  rec users%rowtype; -- don't use reserved word as variable name, use explicit type
BEGIN
  SELECT u.* INTO rec FROM sessions AS t
  JOIN users AS u ON t.user_id = u.id
  WHERE t.token=$1
    AND t.date_last_used > now() - interval '30 minutes'
    AND t.ip_address=$2
    AND NOT u.is_deleted
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM mail AS m
      WHERE m.user_id=u.id AND m.is_confirmed AND NOT m.is_deleted;

  IF FOUND THEN  -- use built-in parameter to test for result of query
    UPDATE sessions SET date_last_used = now() WHERE token=$1;
  ELSE
    -- maybe do other things if there is no result
  END IF;

  RETURN NEXT rec;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

If you return the selected row irrespective of what happens after the `SELECT` query (the `IF FOUND THEN ...` section), then you can even forget about the `rec` variable and write the first statement as:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT u.* ...
```

Note that `RETURN QUERY` does not actually return from the function, it merely adds data to the result set.

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helped me a lot. I actually solved it with `RETURN QUERY SELECT...` since I don't need the record in the function. I didn't know RETURN doesn't end the procedure. A note though: it's `RETURN QUERY ...`, NOT `RETURN NEXT QUERY ...`. The latter causes a syntax error

Comment: Glad to help and thanks for pointing out the error. Answer corrected. `RETURN` actually does finish the function, it just doesn't return any data, you need `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` for that.